# Domain of the adjoint of the Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Given a domain $\Omega \subset\Bbb R^n$, consider the set $D := \{u \in L^2(\Omega)| \Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)\}$, where $-\Delta$ is the Laplacian.
I think this is the domain of the adjoint of $-\Delta$.

My question: is the set $D$ always identical to the Sobolev space $H^2(\Omega)$ ?

Perhaps this is dependent on the boundedness or smoothness of $\Omega$.
I didn't found anything about this problem in functional analysis textbooks.
Are such sources known to anybody ?

Comment: you can find such things in Taylor's book Partial Differential Equations I http://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/1461427266/ref=sr_1_sc_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1389878833&sr=8-2-spell&keywords=tayor+partial

Comment: The book of Renardy-Rogers gives you also information on this. If the boundary is smooth, then yes, in general no.

Comment: When you speak of adjoint of $-\Delta$ you first need to specify the domain of $-\Delta$. How do you define the domain of the Laplacian?

Comment: It u and $\Delta u$ are in $L^2$, it certainly does not follow that $u\in H^2$, unless some restriction is imposed at the boundary.

Comment: Thanks to all for the helpful answers. With respect to the question of Liviu, the domain of the Laplacian should be the space of smooth functions with compact support.